# How can I disable a particular button after click, in a buttons array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My question is, how can I disable a particular button in a Button array depends on a click?
Below there is a SearchField component which consists of multiple buttons in it, I want to disable just the button clicked, but all the buttons turn to disabled, how can I solve this?

```
 state = {
        redirect: false,
        loading: false,
        alreadyAddedFav: false,
        disabled: false
    }




onClickedHandler = (recipe_id, token) => {
        if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            this.setState({ redirect: true })
        }
        else {
            const favData = {
                recipe_id: recipe_id,
                userId: this.props.userId
            }
            if (this.props.favRecipes.length > 0) {

                if (!this.props.favRecipes.some(item => item.recipe_id === recipe_id)) {

                    console.log("added in the loop!")
                    this.props.onFav(favData, token);
                    this.setState({ disabled: true });
                } else {
                    this.setState({ alreadyAddedFav: true })
                    console.log("it is already in the fav list!")
                    console.log(recipe_id)
                }

            } else {
                this.props.onFav(favData, token);
                this.setState({ disabled: true });
            }
        }
    }





     render() {
       return (
                 <SearchResult
                            disabled={this.state.disabled}
                            key={ig.recipe_id}
                            title={ig.title}
                            imgSrc={ig.image_url}
                            clicked={() => this.onClickedHandler(ig.recipe_id, this.props.token)}
                        >
                        </SearchResult>)}
```

Comment: You should keep a separate state property in your parent for the buttons. You can use `index` and can specify which button will be disabled according to this index. In your situation, all the buttons get the same `disabled` property.

Comment: yeah actually I figured out I can use index in the map, but couldn't achieve, if you can show me an example via jsfiddler or JSbin it would be cool

Comment: This probably depends on how you map your buttons. By the way, are those `recipe_id`s can be associated with the buttons somehow? If yes, then maybe you can use the `id`s to specify the disabled buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example, maybe you can enhance this according to your situation.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disableds: [],
  };

  handleClick = i =>
    this.setState( currentState => ( {
      disableds: [ ...currentState.disableds, i ],
    } ) );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Buttons onClick={this.handleClick} disableds={this.state.disableds} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Buttons = ( props ) => {
  const buttons = [ { text: "foo" }, { text: "bar" }, { text: "baz" } ];
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map( ( button, i ) => (
        <button
          key={button.text}
          disabled={props.disableds.includes( i )}
          onClick={() => props.onClick( i )}
        >
          {button.text}
        </button>
      ) )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

What I don't like here is the way I added the `onClick` handler to the button element. In this way, this arrow function will be recreated in every render. Not so big deal but I prefer using function references. To avoid this we can extract each button element into its component and use a separate handler again.

Comment: Yes, I did it! thank you very much, it is an important concept for me to be used for upcoming situations

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it is a nice technique for that kind of situations. I would rather prefer using some unique values to keep the disabled value if possible (like an id) since indexes would be inconsistent.